# I need to compress a file or files using winrar in my c# application

Tags: c#-4.0, compression, directory, winrar

Hi everyone those who are coding.I need to find solution for my application.Actually i did but there a little to go.Here is the code that compress file into rar formatted file that i mentioned.

```
  private const string RarPath = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe";
    List<string> files = new List<string>();




    public void RarFilesAdd(string rarPackagePath, List<string> files)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++) files[i] = string.Format("\"{0}\"", files[i]);
            string dosyaListe = string.Join(" ", files.ToArray());
            string arguman = string.Format("A {0} {1}", String.Format("\"{0}\"", rarPackagePath), dosyaListe);
            Process.Start(String.Format("\"{0}\"", RarPath), arguman);

    }
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@""));
        //RarFilesAdd(@"C:\my\test.rar", files);


        Program nesne = new Program();
        //
        nesne.files.Add(@"C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\a.txt");
        nesne.files.Add(@"C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\a1.txt");
        nesne.RarFilesAdd(@"C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\deneme.rar",nesne.files);
       // nesne.files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\deneme.rar"));

    }
```

This code creates rar file with full path like C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\a1.txt in deneme.rar. But i want that it creates as rar file without any folder in it. I guess i didn't explain in clearly.Now when i clicked deneme.rar it opens directory as Users\Hüseyin\AA . But i want files that situated in AA, keep in deneme.rar directly without any directory or files.I wanted to show screen that i want but i didn't do becaue of rep.

İf is there anyone who will help me it would be greatfull...
Good days everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line you need is:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep "C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\deneme.rar" "C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\a.txt" "C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\a1.txt"
```

In your C# code I miss command `a` for *add files to archive*, but your code works nevertheless as this command is default on running **WinRAR** with no command specified.

And important is to use switch `-ep` which removes the paths from the file names and stores therefore in the RAR archive only the file names.

See text file **Rar.txt** in program files folder of **WinRAR** for details on available commands and switches.

Other command lines which could also work:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep "C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\deneme.rar" "C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\"
```

Adds all files in directory `C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\` to the archive.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep "C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\deneme.rar" "C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\*.txt"
```

Adds only all files with file extension TXT in directory `C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\` to the archive.

Comment: Thanks for ur efforts :)